# Aplicación shiny no filtra bien

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, tidyverse

He generado una aplicación shiny muy sencilla para una clínica nutricionista. El caso es que me genera un fallo que no consigo solucionar. Paso a comentar todo lo que detecto y después dejo el código.

La app es muy simple, tiene una primera pestaña para introducir las medidas antropométricas del paciente, y una segunda pestaña para dar de alta a los nuevos pacientes. Cada pestaña guarda los datos introducidos en un csv diferente, la 1a en uno de mediciones, y la segunda, en uno de pacientes. Además, la 1a pestaña bebe del csv de pacientes a la hora dde generar algunas variables. Entre ellas, extrae un número identificador del paciente mediante filtros. Aquí es donde me produce el error.

En principio, la app va bien. La 1a vez que genero los csv y meto la 1a medición, se realiza los filtros y los guardados correctamente. El problema surge cuando meto una segunda medición, que me devuelve un error diciendo que estoy intentando unir dos df de diferente longitud. El filtro genera un df de longitud 0. Sin embargo, cuando repito todos los pasos de forma externa a la app, va todo bien. He probado con filter(), con subset() y con df[df$variable == dato, ], y me ocurre lo mismo. No sé cuál es el problema. No lo veo.

Al margen de esto, y esto lo cuento más como curiosidad, antes de inicializarse la app, se cargan los dos csv que he comentado antes. Pero no me deja hacerlo con read_csv2(), aun cuando inicio tidyverse al principio, me obliga a hacerlo con read.csv2() o read.delim(). Sin embargo, dentro de server sí utilizo read_csv2() sin problema ninguno. Tampoco sé por qué ocurre esto.

Una última cosa. Como me estaba dando tanto problema la carga de los csv, se me ocurrió que, al iniciar la app por 1a vez, se generasen los csv de forma automática en vez de meterlo yo de base. Por eso veréis un tryCatch(). Bueno, 2. Uno para cada csv. Si los csv no están, da error y los genera. Y si están, simplemente los carga. No sé si esto no es necesario una vez se corrija el problema.

Como comentario final, es posible que esté cargando alguna librería de más, porque suelo arrastrar esa parte de otras app que ya tengo. Y puede que haya alguna duplicidad en un intento de solucionar lo que os comento. Ya no sé qué he probado y qué no.

Os dejo el código de la app completo en una respuesta esta pregunta, que me paso de caracteres y no me deja enviar la pregunta. A ver si conseguís ver lo que yo no. Se me ocurre que pueda ser alguna cosa de formato de los csv. Pero no le encuentro el sentido. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta mañana me ha venido la inspiración y he conseguido solucionarlo. Aprovecho para indicar los cambios extras que he hecho.

He cambiado los tryCatch por el siguiente código (obviamente cambiando los nombres de los objetos por los que tocan):

```
# operaciones previas
pacientes1 <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "pacientes")

if(identical(pacientes1, character(0))) {
    nombre = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
    apellido1 = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
    apellido2 = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
    nombre_car = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
    iniciales = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
    fecha_nacimiento = c("2024-01-01", "2024-01-01")
    id_paciente = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
    sexo = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
    altura = c(1.73, 1.73)
    peso = c(63, 63)
    diabetes = c(FALSE, FALSE)
    colesterol = c(FALSE, FALSE)
    hipertension = c(FALSE, FALSE)
    fumador = c(FALSE, FALSE)
    alcohol = c(FALSE, FALSE)
    deporte = c(FALSE, FALSE)
    otros = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
    objetivo = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
    
    pacientes1 <- data.frame(
        nombre = nombre,
        apellido1 = apellido1,
        apellido2 = apellido2,
        nombre_car = nombre_car,
        iniciales = iniciales,
        fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento,
        id_paciente = id_paciente,
        sexo = sexo,
        altura = altura,
        peso = peso,
        diabetes = diabetes,
        colesterol = colesterol,
        hipertension = hipertension,
        fumador = fumador,
        alcohol = alcohol,
        deporte = deporte,
        otros = otros,
        objetivo = objetivo
    )
    
    pacientes1$fecha_nacimiento <- as.Date(pacientes1$fecha_nacimiento, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
    
    write_csv2(pacientes1, "pacientes.csv")
    
    pacientes_nombre <- pacientes1$nombre_car
} else {
    pacientes1 <- read.csv2("pacientes.csv") # carga la bbdd de pacientes
    pacientes1 <- pacientes1[pacientes1$nombre != "_nombre", ]
    
    pacientes_nombre <- pacientes1$nombre_car
}
```

Y he cambiado los observerEvent que cogían uno de los df previamente cargados y las funciones de guardar datos por lo siguiente:

```
observeEvent(input$guardar1, {
        mediciones2 <- guardar_mediciones()
        mediciones1 <- read_csv2("mediciones.csv")
        mediciones1 <- mediciones1[mediciones1$nombre != "_nombre", ]
        mediciones1 <- drop_na(mediciones1)
        mediciones1 <- rbind(mediciones1, mediciones2)
        write_csv2(mediciones1, "mediciones.csv")
    })

guardar_mediciones <- function(){
        #aquí hay más código previo
        df1<- read_csv2("pacientes.csv")
        df1 <- df1[df1$nombre_car == nombre, ]
        #aquí hay más código posterior
}
```

Le obligo a cargar el archivo csv de nuevo, aunque esté previamente cargado. Cada vez que lo carga, una vez hechas todas las operaciones, lo vuelve a guardar, para no perder datos si lo vuelve a cargar más adelante. No sé si es la mejor forma, pero hace que funcione la aplicación, que es lo que yo quiero.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Código hasta UI:

```
# Carga de librerías
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tinytex)
library(markdown)
library(rmarkdown)
library(ggpubr)
library(psycModel)
library(pagedown)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(webshot)
library(shiny) # la libreria shiny debe ir la última para que el resto funcione (no le encuentro el sentido, pero si no, no me funciona el script)
library(shinyWidgets)


# operaciones previas
tryCatch(
    expr = {
        pacientes1 <- read.csv2("pacientes.csv") # carga la bbdd de pacientes
        pacientes1 <- pacientes1[pacientes1$nombre != "_nombre", ]
    },
    error = function(e){
        nombre = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        apellido1 = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        apellido2 = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        nombre_car = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        iniciales = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        fecha_nacimiento = c("2024-01-01", "2024-01-01")
        id_paciente = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        sexo = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        altura = c(1.73, 1.73)
        peso = c(63, 63)
        diabetes = c(FALSE, FALSE)
        colesterol = c(FALSE, FALSE)
        hipertension = c(FALSE, FALSE)
        fumador = c(FALSE, FALSE)
        alcohol = c(FALSE, FALSE)
        deporte = c(FALSE, FALSE)
        otros = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        objetivo = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        
        pacientes1 <- data.frame(
            nombre = nombre,
            apellido1 = apellido1,
            apellido2 = apellido2,
            nombre_car = nombre_car,
            iniciales = iniciales,
            fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento,
            id_paciente = id_paciente,
            sexo = sexo,
            altura = altura,
            peso = peso,
            diabetes = diabetes,
            colesterol = colesterol,
            hipertension = hipertension,
            fumador = fumador,
            alcohol = alcohol,
            deporte = deporte,
            otros = otros,
            objetivo = objetivo
        )
        
        pacientes1$fecha_nacimiento <- as.Date(pacientes1$fecha_nacimiento, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
        
        write_csv2(pacientes1, "pacientes.csv")
    }
)


tryCatch(
    expr = {
        mediciones1 <- read.csv2("mediciones.csv") # carga la bbdd de mediciones
        mediciones1 <- mediciones1[mediciones1$nombre != "_nombre", ]
    },
    error = function(e){
        nombre = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        fecha_medicion = c("2005-01-01", "2005-01-01")
        id_paciente = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        id_medicion = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        peso_kg = c(63, 63)
        grasa_porc = c(63, 63)
        masa_osea_kg = c(63, 63)
        agua_porc = c(63, 63)
        musculo_kg = c(63, 63)
        musculo_porc = c(63, 63)
        cond_fisica = c(63, 63)
        metabolismo_kcal = c(63, 63)
        edad_metabolica = c(63, 63)
        grasa_vis_kg = c(63, 63)
        brazo_cm = c(63, 63)
        muslo_cm = c(63, 63)
        cintura_cm = c(63, 63)
        cadera_cm = c(63, 63)
        tricipital_cm = c(63, 63)
        subescapular_cm = c(63, 63)
        suprailiaco_cm = c(63, 63)
        abdominal_cm = c(63, 63)
        comodidad_plan = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        recuperacion_entr = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        energia_sensacion = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        sue_calidad = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        agua_ingesta = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        estre_diarrea = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        sensacion_g = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        otros = c("_nombre", "_nombre")
        
        mediciones1 <- data.frame(
            nombre = nombre,
            fecha_medicion = fecha_medicion,
            id_paciente = id_paciente,
            id_medicion = id_medicion,
            peso_kg = peso_kg,
            grasa_porc = grasa_porc,
            masa_osea_kg = masa_osea_kg,
            agua_porc = agua_porc,
            musculo_kg = musculo_kg,
            musculo_porc = musculo_porc,
            cond_fisica = cond_fisica,
            metabolismo_kcal = metabolismo_kcal,
            edad_metabolica = edad_metabolica,
            grasa_vis_kg = grasa_vis_kg,
            brazo_cm = brazo_cm,
            muslo_cm = muslo_cm,
            cintura_cm = cintura_cm,
            cadera_cm = cadera_cm,
            tricipital_cm = tricipital_cm,
            subescapular_cm = subescapular_cm,
            suprailiaco_cm = suprailiaco_cm,
            abdominal_cm = abdominal_cm,
            comodidad_plan = comodidad_plan,
            recuperacion_entr = recuperacion_entr,
            energia_sensacion = energia_sensacion,
            sue_calidad = sue_calidad,
            agua_ingesta = agua_ingesta,
            estre_diarrea = estre_diarrea,
            sensacion_g = sensacion_g,
            otros = otros
        )
        
        mediciones1$fecha_medicion <- as.Date(mediciones1$fecha_medicion, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
        
        write_csv2(mediciones1, "mediciones.csv")
    }
)

# 1a parte de la APP, es el código para generar todas las variables de entrada y salida y su disposición en la APP
ui <- fixedPage(
    
    # crea una cabecera, aquí pondré los logos
    titlePanel(
        
        # de esta forma se crean 3 partes, una en cada línea. La 1a es la imagen del logo. La 2a genera un espacio en blanco. La 3a es el título
        div(
            img(
                src = "esther_java.jpg", # el archivo de imagen tiene que estar en el mismo directorio que el script de la APP
                width = "100%" # proporción del archivo de imagen en anchura
            ), 
            
            br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
            br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
            
            "Sistema de gestión de Historias Clínicas" # título de la APP, aparece debajo del logo
        )
    ),
    
    
    # crea una sección con pestañas para explicar la APP
    tabsetPanel(
        
        # 1a pestaña, para introducir las mediciones de los pacientes
        tabPanel(
            tags$b("Nueva medición"), # título de la pestaña en negrita
            icon = tags$img(src = "nueva_medicion.png", height = 20, width = 20), # añade un icono a la pestaña
            
            br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
            
            
            style = "font-size: 14px", # establece en tamaño 20 de la letra de la sección. Es código CSS
            
            br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
            
            selectInput(
                "nombre1", # nombre de la variable
                label = "Nombre del paciente", # título del cuadro
                choices = sort(pacientes1$nombre_car), # utiliza la lista de nombres guardada en la variable NOMBRE_CAR de PACIENTES1
                selected = 0 # en teoría, con esto no debería aparecer ningún nombre seleccionado al iniciar la APP, pero no ocurre así
            ),
            
            br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
            
            dateInput(
                "fecha1", # nombre de la variable
                label = "Fecha de la medición", # título del cuadro
                format = "dd-mm-yyyy"
            ),
            
            br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
            
            br(tags$b(HTML("<center>VALORACIÓN PLAN NUTRICIONAL</center>"))), # título para el resto de la sección
            
            # genera una columna centrada con diferentes variables (radioButtons) con una escala de 5 valores, con solo 1 válido
            column(12,
                   align = "center",
                   radioButtons(
                       "plan1",
                       label = "Comodidad para seguir el plan nutricional",
                       choices = list("Nada cómodo", "Poco cómodo", "Normal", "Cómodo", "Muy cómodo"),
                       inline = TRUE,
                       selected = 0
                   ),
                   
                   br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
                   
                   radioButtons(
                       "recuperacion1",
                       label = "Recuperación post-entrenamiento",
                       choices = list("Muy mala", "Mala", "Normal", "Buena", "Muy buena"),
                       inline = TRUE,
                       selected = 0
                   ),
                   
                   br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
                   
                   radioButtons(
                       "energia1",
                       label = "Sensación de energía",
                       choices = list("Muy poca", "Poca", "Normal", "Buena", "Muy buena"),
                       inline = TRUE,
                       selected = 0
                   ),
                   
                   br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
                   
                   radioButtons(
                       "dormir1",
                       label = "Calidad del sueño",
                       choices = list("Muy malo", "Malo", "Normal", "Bueno", "Muy bueno"),
                       inline = TRUE,
                       selected = 0
                   ),
                   
                   br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
                   
                   radioButtons(
                       "agua1",
                       label = "Ingesta de agua",
                       choices = list("Muy poca", "Poca", "Normal", "Mucha", "Muy mucha"),
                       inline = TRUE,
                       selected = 0
                   ),
                   
                   br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
                   
                   radioButtons(
                       "baño1",
                       label = "Estreñimiento/Diarrea",
                       choices = list("Estreñimiento", "Dificultad", "Normal", "Blando", "Diarrea"),
                       inline = TRUE,
                       selected = 0
                   ),
                   
                   br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
                   
                   radioButtons(
                       "sensacion1",
                       label = "Sensación general",
                       choices = list("Muy mala", "Mala", "Normal", "Buena", "Muy buena"),
                       inline = TRUE,
                       selected = 0
                   ),
                   
                   br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
                   
                   # cuadro para introducir texto libre
                   textAreaInput(
                       "otros2",
                       label = "Otros datos de interés",
                       rows = 5,
                       placeholder = "Comentarios generales"
                   ),
                   
                   br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
                   br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
            ),
            
            br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
            
            br(tags$b(HTML("<center>VALORACIÓN ANTROPOMÉTRICA</center>"))), # título para el resto de la sección
            
            # establece una sección con dos columnas para ordenar los diferentes valores a recoger, todos numéricos
            fluidRow(
                column(
                    width = 6,
                    
                    # Contenido de la primera columna
                    numericInput(
                        "peso1",
                        label = "peso (kg)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "grasa1",
                        label = "% grasa",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "hueso1",
                        label = "masa ósea (kg)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "agua2",
                        label = "% agua corporal",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "musculo1",
                        label = "masa muscular (kg)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "fisico1",
                        label = "condición física",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "metabolismo1",
                        label = "metabolismo basal (kcal)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "edad1",
                        label = "edad metabólica (años)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "grasa2",
                        label = "grasa visceral (kg)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                ),
                
                column(
                    width = 6,
                    
                    # Contenido de la segunda columna
                    numericInput(
                        "per1",
                        label = "perímetro de brazo (cm)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "per2",
                        label = "perímetro de muslo (cm)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "per3",
                        label = "perímetro de cintura (cm)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "per4",
                        label = "perímetro de cadera (cm)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "pliegue1",
                        label = "pliegue tricipital (cm)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "pliegue2",
                        label = "pliegue subescapular (cm)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "pliegue3",
                        label = "pliegue suprailíaco (cm)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "pliegue4",
                        label = "pliegue abdominal (cm)",
                        value = NULL # así no se muestra ningún valor al iniciar la APP
                    )
                )
            ),
            
            # genera una sección para los botones de interacción
            fluidRow(
                tags$hr(), # añande una línea horizontal
                br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
                
                # botón para borrar el contenido introducido en la pestaña (no lo borra de la base de datos)
                column(
                    width = 2,
                    actionButton("borrar1",
                                 img(src = "borrar.png", height = 60, width = 60), # añade un icono a la pestaña
                                 icon = NULL,
                                 style = "background-color: #F9F9F9;"
                    )
                ),
                
                # botón para guardar en la base de datos los datos introducidos en la sección
                column(
                    width = 2,
                    actionButton("guardar1",
                                 img(src = "salvar.png", height = 60, width = 60), # añade un icono a la pestaña
                                 icon = NULL,
                                 style = "background-color: #F9F9F9;"
                    )
                ),
                
                # botón para generar un informe en pdf
                column(
                    width = 2,
                    downloadButton("pdf1",
                                   img(src = "pdf.png", height = 60, width = 60), # añade un icono a la pestaña
                                   icon = NULL,
                                   style = "background-color: #F9F9F9;"
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        
        # 2a pestaña, para intoducir nuevos pacientes en la base de datos, es necesario si no está el paciente en la base
        tabPanel(
            tags$b("Nuevo paciente"), # título de la pestaña en negrita
            icon = tags$img(src = "nuevo_paciente.png", height = 20, width = 20), # añade un icono a la pestaña
            
            br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
            
            
            style = "font-size: 14px", # establece en tamaño 20 de la letra de la sección. Es código CSS
            
            br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
            
            # establece una sección con dos columnas para ordenar los diferentes valores a recoger
            fluidRow(
                column(
                    width = 6,
                    
                    # Contenido de la primera columna
                    textInput(
                        "nombre2",
                        label = "Nombre",
                        value = NULL
                    ),
                    
                    textInput(
                        "apellido1",
                        label = "Primer apellido",
                        value = NULL
                    ),
                    
                    textInput(
                        "apellido2",
                        label = "Segundo apellido",
                        value = NULL
                    ),
                    
                    dateInput(
                        "fecha2",
                        label = "Fecha de nacimiento",
                        value = "",
                        format = "dd-mm-yyyy"
                    ),
                    
                    radioButtons(
                        "sexo1",
                        label = "Sexo",
                        choiceNames = list("Hombre", "Mujer"),
                        choiceValues = list("Hombre", "Mujer"),
                        inline = TRUE,
                        selected = 0
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "altura1",
                        label = "Altura (m)",
                        value = NULL
                    ),
                    
                    numericInput(
                        "peso2",
                        label = "Peso (kg)",
                        value = NULL
                    ),
                    
                ),
                
                column(
                    width = 6,
                    
                    # Contenido de la segunda columna
                    checkboxInput(
                        "diabetes1",
                        label = tags$b("Diabetes mellitus"),
                        value = FALSE
                    ),
                    
                    checkboxInput(
                        "colesterol1",
                        label = tags$b("Colesterol"),
                        value = FALSE
                    ),
                    
                    checkboxInput(
                        "tension1",
                        label = tags$b("Hipertensión"),
                        value = FALSE
                    ),
                    
                    checkboxInput(
                        "fumar1",
                        label = tags$b("Fumador"),
                        value = FALSE
                    ),
                    
                    checkboxInput(
                        "beber1",
                        label = tags$b("Alcohol"),
                        value = FALSE
                    ),
                    
                    textAreaInput(
                        "otros1",
                        label = "Otros datos de interés",
                        rows = 5,
                        placeholder = "Alergias, intervenciones quirúgicas, otras enfermedades..."
                    ),
                    
                    textAreaInput(
                        "deporte1",
                        label = "Deportes practicados",
                        rows = 3,
                        placeholder = "Actividad deportiva del paciente"
                    ),
                    
                    textAreaInput(
                        "objetivo1",
                        label = "Objetivo",
                        rows = 3,
                        placeholder = "Objetivo del paciente"
                    )
                )
            ),
            
            fluidRow(
                tags$hr(), # añande una línea horizontal
                br(), # introduce un salto de párrafo sin contenido
                
                column(
                    width = 2,
                    actionButton("borrar2",
                                 img(src = "borrar.png", height = 60, width = 60), # añade un icono a la pestaña
                                 icon = NULL,
                                 style = "background-color: #F9F9F9;"
                    )
                ),
                
                column(
                    width = 2,
                    actionButton("guardar2",
                                 img(src = "salvar.png", height = 60, width = 60), # añade un icono a la pestaña
                                 icon = NULL,
                                 style = "background-color: #F9F9F9;"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    
    tags$hr(), # añade una línea horizontal
    p(tags$b("Designed by @atpbsc.")) # pie de página 
)
```

Comment: Esto deberían ser respuestas.... en vez de eso, forman parte de la pregunta. Uno pensaría que con algo de reputación y casi un año en el sitio habrías entendido como mínimo el formato del mismo, puesto que te han respondido otras veces! Por favor, añade toda la información a la PREGUNTA, y NO EN RESPUESTAS! Por otro lado, debes proporcionar un [mre] no absolutamente todo el código...

Comment: Hola, Benito-B. Gracias por tu comentario. Tengo claro que son respuestas. Como explico en mi pregunta, no me deja poner todo lo que explico en la pregunta.  Desconozco si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo. Si es el caso y tú la conoces, te agradecería que la indicaras. En cuanto a poner todo el código, lo hago por que no sé dónde está el problema. Si lo supiese, lo habría hecho así, o no haría la pregunta. De nuevo, gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Código desde SERVER

```
# 2a parte de la APP, es el cóigo donde se realizan todas las operaciones que hace la APP
server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    # limpia los campos de la ventana "nueva medición"
    observeEvent(input$borrar1, {
        updateSelectInput(session, "nombre1", selected = 0)
        updateRadioButtons(session, "plan1", selected = 0)
        updateRadioButtons(session, "recuperacion1", selected = 0)
        updateRadioButtons(session, "energia1", selected = 0)
        updateRadioButtons(session, "dormir1", selected = 0)
        updateRadioButtons(session, "agua1", selected = 0)
        updateRadioButtons(session, "baño1", selected = 0)
        updateRadioButtons(session, "sensacion1", selected = 0)
        updateRadioButtons(session, "otros2", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "peso1", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "grasa1", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "hueso1", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "agua2", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "musculo1", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "fisico1", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "metabolismo1", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "edad1", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "grasa2", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "per1", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "per2", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "per3", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "per4", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "pliegue1", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "pliegue2", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "pliegue3", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "pliegue4", value = NULL)
    })
    
    # limpia los campos de la ventana "nuevo paciente"
    observeEvent(input$borrar2, {
        updateTextInput(session, "nombre2", value = "")
        updateTextInput(session, "apellido1", value = "")
        updateTextInput(session, "apellido2", value = "")
        updateDateInput(session, "fecha2", value = "")
        updateRadioButtons(session, "sexo1", selected = 0)
        updateNumericInput(session, "altura1", value = NULL)
        updateNumericInput(session, "peso2", value = NULL)
        updateCheckboxInput(session, "diabetes1", value = FALSE)
        updateCheckboxInput(session, "colesterol1", value = FALSE)
        updateCheckboxInput(session, "tension1", value = FALSE)
        updateCheckboxInput(session, "fumar1", value = FALSE)
        updateCheckboxInput(session, "beber1", value = FALSE)
        updateTextAreaInput(session, "otros1", value = "")
        updateTextAreaInput(session, "deporte1", value = "")
        updateTextAreaInput(session, "objetivo1", value = "")
    })
    
    # guardar mediciones
    guardar_mediciones <- function(){
        nombre <- input$nombre1
        nombre <- as.character(nombre)
        fecha1 <- input$fecha1
        fecha_medicion <- as.Date(fecha1, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
        
        df1<- pacientes1
        df1 <- df1[df1$nombre_car == nombre, ]
        
        id_paciente <- unique(df1$id_paciente)
        id_medicion <- paste0(fecha1, id_paciente)
        id_medicion <- gsub("-", "", id_medicion)
        peso_kg <- input$peso1
        grasa_porc <- input$grasa1
        masa_osea_kg <- input$hueso1
        agua_porc <- input$agua2
        musculo_kg <- input$musculo1
        musculo_porc <- (musculo_kg / peso_kg) * 100
        cond_fisica <- input$fisico1
        metabolismo_kcal <- input$metabolismo1
        edad_metabolica <- input$edad1
        grasa_vis_kg <- input$grasa2
        brazo_cm <- input$per1
        muslo_cm <- input$per2
        cintura_cm <- input$per3
        cadera_cm <- input$per4
        tricipital_cm <- input$pliegue1
        subescapular_cm <- input$pliegue2
        suprailiaco_cm <- input$pliegue3
        abdominal_cm <- input$pliegue4
        comodidad_plan <- input$plan1
        recuperacion_entr <- input$recuperacion1
        energia_sensacion <- input$energia1
        sue_calidad <- input$dormir1
        agua_ingesta <- input$agua1
        estre_diarrea <- input$baño1
        sensacion_g <- input$sensacion1
        otros <- input$otros2
        
        
        mediciones2 <- data.frame (nombre, fecha_medicion, id_paciente, id_medicion, 
                                   peso_kg, grasa_porc, masa_osea_kg, agua_porc, musculo_kg, musculo_porc, 
                                   cond_fisica, metabolismo_kcal, edad_metabolica, grasa_vis_kg, 
                                   brazo_cm, muslo_cm, cintura_cm, cadera_cm, 
                                   tricipital_cm, subescapular_cm, suprailiaco_cm, abdominal_cm, 
                                   comodidad_plan, recuperacion_entr, energia_sensacion, sue_calidad, agua_ingesta, estre_diarrea, sensacion_g, otros)
        
        mediciones2$fecha_medicion <- as.Date(mediciones2$fecha_medicion, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
        
        mediciones2
    }
    
    observeEvent(input$guardar1, {
        mediciones2 <- guardar_mediciones()
        mediciones3 <- drop_na(mediciones1)
        mediciones3 <- rbind(mediciones3, mediciones2)
        write_csv2(mediciones3, "mediciones.csv")
    })
    
    informe <- function(){
        mediciones2 <- guardar_mediciones()
        mediciones2 <- select(mediciones2, 
                              nombre, fecha_medicion, id_paciente, id_medicion, 
                              peso_kg, grasa_porc, masa_osea_kg, agua_porc, musculo_kg, musculo_porc, 
                              cond_fisica, metabolismo_kcal, edad_metabolica, grasa_vis_kg, 
                              brazo_cm, muslo_cm, cintura_cm, cadera_cm, 
                              tricipital_cm, subescapular_cm, suprailiaco_cm, abdominal_cm)
        
        # instrucción para pasar los datos
        rmarkdown::render(
            input = "report.Rmd", # llama al archivo de Rmarkdown
            output_file = "report.html", # nombre del archivo de salida
            params = list(datos_shiny = mediciones2) # datos que pasa al archivo Rmarkdown
        )
    }
    
    output$pdf1 <- downloadHandler( 
        
        # genera el nombre del archivo
        filename = function(){
            nombre <- input$nombre1
            fecha1 <- input$fecha1
            fecha1 <- gsub("-", "", fecha1)
            
            df1 <- pacientes1
            df1 <- df1[df1$nombre_car == nombre, ]
            
            apellido1 <- unique(df1$apellido1)
            apellido2 <- unique(df1$apellido2)
            nombre <- unique(df1$apellido2)
            
            paste0(apellido1, "_", apellido2, "_",nombre, "_", fecha1, ".pdf")
        },
        
        # función paragenerar el informe
        content = function(file){
            
            informe1 <- informe() # llama a la función que envía los datos alarchivo Rmarkdown
            
            margenes <- list(top = "1cm", right = "1cm", bottom = "1cm", left = "1cm")
            
            margenes <- list(
                zoom = 1,
                delay = 0,
                cliprect = "-1000,-1000,1000,1000", # Ajusta el área de recorte para incluir todo el contenido
                margin = margenes # Márgenes: superior, derecho, inferior, izquierdo (en pulgadas)
            )
            
            html_to_pdf(informe1, "report.pdf", options = margenes) # crea una copia en pdf del archivo html generado
            
            file.rename("report.pdf", file) # cambia el nombre del archivo pdf generado
        }
    )
    
    # guardar pacientes
    guardar_pacientes <- function(){
        nombre <- input$nombre2
        apellido1 <- input$apellido1
        apellido2 <- input$apellido2        
        nombre_car <- paste0(apellido1, " ", apellido2, ", ", nombre)
        iniciales <- paste0(substr(nombre, 1, 1), substr(apellido1, 1, 1), substr(apellido2, 1, 1))
        fecha_nacimiento1 <- input$fecha2
        fecha_nacimiento <- as.Date(fecha_nacimiento1, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
        id_paciente <- gsub("-", "", fecha_nacimiento1)
        id_paciente <- paste0(id_paciente, iniciales)
        sexo <- input$sexo1
        altura <- input$altura1
        peso <- input$peso2
        diabetes <- input$diabetes1
        colesterol <- input$colesterol1
        hipertension <- input$tension1
        fumador <- input$fumar1
        alcohol <- input$beber1
        otros <- input$otros1
        deporte <- input$deporte1
        objetivo <- input$objetivo1
        
        pacientes2 <- data.frame(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, nombre_car, iniciales, fecha_nacimiento, id_paciente, sexo, 
                                 altura, peso, diabetes, colesterol, hipertension, fumador, alcohol, deporte, otros, objetivo)
        
        pacientes2$fecha_nacimiento <- as.Date(pacientes2$fecha_nacimiento, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
        
        pacientes2
    }
    
    observeEvent(input$guardar2, {
        pacientes2 <- guardar_pacientes()
        pacientes3 <- pacientes1
        pacientes3 <- drop_na(pacientes3)
        pacientes3 <- rbind(pacientes3, pacientes2)
        pacientes1 <- pacientes3
        write_csv2(pacientes3, "pacientes.csv")
        updateSelectInput(session, "nombre1", choices = sort(pacientes1$nombre_car))
    })
}

# compilación de la APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```